# Change font color based on variable wont work

Tags: css

I want the font color of the tekst in my table changed based on a value stored in my sql database. I have a variable that gets the color hex from an other sql table. It works for the background but it wont work for the font color.

This is what works.

`<td bgcolor="#<?= $cat_color ?> "><?= $rij->cat_color ?></td>`

This is what i tried

`<td color="#<?= $cat_color ?> "><?= $rij->cat_color ?></td>`

The color of the font i not changing. please help, besides this i have tried many things..

Comment: bgcolor is deprecated and as far as I know a color attribute never existed. Try using inline CSS instead... for example style="color:#<?= $cat_color ?>;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

color is not an allowed attribute of td. Use style="color:#cc0000" instead.

example:

```
<td style="color:#<?= $cat_color ?>;">test 2</td>
```

maybe you should consider to use a dynamic class name. but it depends of the general code context of your project.